# How to display multiple rows of variables through an html tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 3 pages, an html, javascript and php file. When one button is pressed in the html page, the php page searches a database for rows with the button's name as key and brings back a number of rows. I want to display all those rows in the html page but when I send back the data, it doesn't get displayed. here is my code from the three pages.

Html page

```
<button name = 'science'>      Science</button>
<button name = 'engineering'>  Engineering</button>
<button name = 'math'>         Math</button>
<button name = 'law'>          Law</button>
<button name = 'arts'>         Arts</button>
<button name = 'business'>     Business</button>
<button name = 'fiction'>      Fiction</button>
<button name = 'selfhelp'>     Self Help</button>
<button name = 'labequipment'> Lab Equipment</button>

<p id = 'feedback'></p>

<script type ="text/javascript" src ="jquery.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="catselect.js"></script>
```

javascript page

```
$(":button").click(function(){
    var cat = $(this).attr("name");

    $.get("trier.php",{input: cat}, function(data){
        $("#feedback").html(data);
    }); 
});
```

php page

```
if(isset($_GET['input'])){
    $catt = $_GET['input'];

        $info = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE (Category = '$catt')";

        while(mysqli_query($conn,$info)){
            $information = mysqli_query($conn,$info);
            $intel = mysqli_fetch_assoc($information);  

            echo $intel['Title'];
            echo nl2br("\n");
            echo $intel['Course'];
        }
}
```

I want to display many rows including a 'title' column and a 'course' columnn in the tag in the php page with the id = "display". Any ideas as to how I can modify my code to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`$(":button")` should be `$("button")`

u can use php echo html of table but i suggest use json  or use angularjs

id should not change frequently, `id = "display" better use class="display"` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can do the simple way like how @Yanjun Lin suggested using html table
on your php:
    if(isset($_GET['input'])){
        $catt = $_GET['input'];

```
        $info = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE (Category = '$catt')";
        $html='';
        while(mysqli_query($conn,$info)){
            $information = mysqli_query($conn,$info);
            $intel = mysqli_fetch_assoc($information);  
            $html=$html.'<tr>';
            //echo $intel['Title'];
            //echo nl2br("\n");
            //echo $intel['Course'];

            $html=$html.'<td>'.$intel['Title'].'</td>';
            $html=$html.'<td>'.$intel['Course'].'</td>';
            $html=$html.'</tr>';
        }
       echo $html;
```

on your javascript:

```
$("button").click(function(){
var cat = $(this).attr("name");

$.get("trier.php",{input: cat}, function(data){
    $("#feedback").html(data);
});
```

on your html (change `<p>` tag to `<table>` tag):

```
<button name = 'science'>      Science</button>
    <button name = 'engineering'>  Engineering</button>
    <button name = 'math'>         Math</button>
    <button name = 'law'>          Law</button>
    <button name = 'arts'>         Arts</button>
    <button name = 'business'>     Business</button>
    <button name = 'fiction'>      Fiction</button>
    <button name = 'selfhelp'>     Self Help</button>
    <button name = 'labequipment'> Lab Equipment</button>

<table id = 'feedback'></table>

<script type ="text/javascript" src ="jquery.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="catselect.js"></script>
```

I did not test on your php, but do hope it works... also [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lech/L60mt8zq/) it would look something like this in javascript and html only. Also do consider using use json for proper standard like how @Yanjun Lin suggest